# How to configure sanity preview to work on live?

Tags: sanity

I'm using the starter template sanity provides https://github.com/sanity-io/template-nextjs-personal-website

The preview is looking for the location from `req.query` object which is console logging as empty. This causes the `resolveHref` function to return undefined

How to solve this or find the page route to preview another way?

```
function redirectToPreview(
  res: NextApiResponse<string | void>,
  previewData: { token?: string },
  Location: string
): void {
  res.writeHead(307, {
    Location: Location,
  })
  res.end()
}

const _client = createClient({ projectId, dataset, apiVersion, useCdn })

export default async function preview(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<string | void>
) {
  const previewData: { token?: string } = {}
  if (
    process.env.SANITY_REQUIRE_PREVIEW_SECRET === 'true' &&
    !req.query.secret
  ) {
    return res.status(401).send('Invalid secret')
  }

  if (req.query.secret) {
    const token = process.env.SANITY_API_READ_TOKEN
    if (!token) {
      throw new Error(
        'A secret is provided but there is no `SANITY_API_READ_TOKEN` environment variable setup.'
      )
    }
    const client = _client.withConfig({ useCdn: false, token })
    const secret = await getSecret(client, previewSecretId)
    if (req.query.secret !== secret) {
      return res.status(401).send('Invalid secret')
    }
    previewData.token = token
  }

  const href = resolveHref(
    req.query.documentType as string,
    req.query.slug as string
  )

  if (!href) {
    return res
      .status(400)
      .send(
        'Unable to resolve preview URL based on the current document type and slug'
      )
  }

  return redirectToPreview(res, previewData, href)
}
```